# Is it possible to convert LVDS (TI DS90c241/124) differential signals to optical signals?

Tags: differential, lvds, fiber-optics

I have a circuit that uses the TI DS90C241 DS90C124 serdes pair to serialize 24bits of data from one board to the other. Either due to electrical interference or the transmission media's characteristics I unable to go beyond 14 MHz of serializer clocking. Beyond that the de-serializer begins to loose lock.

I want to evaluate fiber optic transmission a try without changing my circuit, so are there any off the shelf converters available that take in LVDS signals and translate them to fiber optic and back at the other end?

Thanks

Comment: At 14 Mbps, any LVDS-to-CMOS converter, and possibly a buffer transistor, and an LED, will do it.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, yes why not if that would been the case. 

Actually the data rate is much higher than 14Mbps. 14MHz that I mentioned is the clock that I provide to the DS90C serializer. At this clock in converts 24 bit of parallel data to serial data, adds some clock recovery and framing information, so the LVDS bit rate would be approximately 360Mbps (14x24) slightly more actually accounting for the framing and clock synchronization data

Comment: Looking at the datasheet, there is a VODSELECT control pin. If you set it high you get a minimum 450 mV differential output voltage. WIth this setting it's very likely the chip can drive an SFP transceiver that expects AC-coupled (P)ECL inputs.